# Entity Framework import and use stored procedure which returns different result sets depending on input

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on a migration project, where I am migrating an web forms app to a ASP.NET MVC 4 app.

I have come across this one scenario with which I need a little help.

In the old web form project I have stored proc like...

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TestMultipleResultSet]
    @input VARCHAR
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT * FROM Electronics
        WHERE name = @input
    )
    BEGIN
        SELECT 101 AS errorcode
        RETURN
    END

    SELECT * FROM Electronics 
    WHERE name = @input
END
```

like the above `if not exist` check, there are many other checks with gives different `select * from` as resultset.

Now I want to use Entity framework to execute this stored procedure, so I imported the function and created a complex type using the `Get Column Information` + `Create Complex Type` option which EF provides.

Now it runs when I enter a valid @input which executes `SELECT * FROM Electronics WHERE name = @input` but when I enter an input which is not present instead of returning me a 101 error code it gives me an error. An exception is thrown.

Exception details

> The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'testEFModel.GetTestResults_Result1'. A member of the type, 'id', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.

How should I solve this ?

Comment: It's a **really bad idea** to return different shapes of result sets from a single stored procedure. EF doesn't support this - and most likely never will. Redesign your system - use one stored procedure for each type/shape of result you might be getting ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it really necessary that you use the stored procedure?

Using EF you could simply do:

```csharp
var filteredItems = dc.Electronics.Where(e => e.Name == @input).ToList();

if (!filteredItems.Any())
    throw new ApplicationException("No items were found according to criteria");
```

***Note:** I have not actually run the above code; it just illustrates the idea doing things the EF way*